# Starting a Service and referencing objects

Tags: java, android, service

i want to create a service in android studio which runs a client. 
I created my own serviceclass and i could start the service with

```
startService(new Intent(this,Client.class));
```

on my MainActivity.
Now i want a reference object from the Client.class to the MainActivity.
My problem is that there is no constructor.
I don't want to do it static...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional, you don't get a direct reference to your service. The Android framework takes care of starting and stop your services automatically. The same goes for Activities. If you need to perform actions on a Service there recommend practices is to send intents. If service is providing data for someone to consume you can use a broadcast receiver. If you want an actual object to directly execute methods on, you will need to make the service a bound one, and retrieve a binder object that will execute the calls on your behalf. It's a little more work involved but nothing difficult.

Here is a link to the Android documentation on [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#java).

Comment: @Kolone13 The linked article has a very simple example at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

just use a setter. You can call the setter in an overidden onConnectionEstablished method provided by the ServiceConnection interface.

Read "Binding to a service" here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services